# Redirect link in swift ui

Tags: swift, xcode, redirect, swiftui

I am working on a web application for iOS. I would like that when the user clicks on the link sign in the link is redirected. I need this because I need to paste the token created for the user behind it. For now, the redirect link is nu.nl. I have this now, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I am not familiar with the language swift ui. Thanks in advance for your help :)

**Contentview**

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebView(url: URL(string:"https://ferocity.bytemountains.com/client")!).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**Webview**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    
    let url: URL
    let webView = WKWebView()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
        return webView
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Swift.Void) {
            if(navigationAction.navigationType == .other) {
                if navigationAction.request.url != nil {
                    //do what you need with url
                    webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://nu.nl/")!))
                }
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
                return
            }
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }

    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    }
    
    
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ8BL.jpg)

Comment: Does web view `decidePolicyFor` method is called?

Comment: If you have helpful my answer then please approve it. So, other users that faces same issues will find it as helpful and needful.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `Coordinator` and then need to conform the `WKNavigationDelegate` to call its delegate methods.

```
struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {

    let url: URL
    var webView = WKWebView()
   
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    //Conform to WKNavigationDelegate protocol here and declare its delegate 
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: WebView

        init(_ parent: WebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        
            //Navigate to other URL if user clicks on the sign in link
            if navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString == "https://sso.bytemountains.com/?clientId=2" {
                webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://nu.nl/")!))
            }            
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
}
```